# Reverse geocoding in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

```
getAddress(lat: number, lng: number) {
  console.log('Finding Address');
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    let request = { LatLng: latlng };
    geocoder.geocode({ latlng: latlng }, (results, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        let result = results[0];
        let rsltAdrComponent = result.address_components;
        let resultLength = rsltAdrComponent.length;
        if (result != null) {
          console.log(rsltAdrComponent[resultLength - 8].short_name)
          // this.address = rsltAdrComponent[resultLength - 8].short_name;
        } else {
          console.log('No address available!');
        }
    }
  });
}
```

}

I am trying to get address from lat & long, But getting this error

**Argument of type '{ latlng: LatLng; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GeocoderRequest'.**

**Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'latlng' does not exist in type 'GeocoderRequest'.**

How to achieve reverse geocoding in angular?

Comment: http://definitelytyped.org/docs/googlemaps--google.maps/interfaces/google.maps.geocoderrequest.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the key to location as shown in the code snippet below:

```
getAddress(lat: number, lng: number) {
   console.log('Finding Address');
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
      let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      let request = { LatLng: latlng };
      geocoder.geocode({ location: latlng }, (results, status) => {
         if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            let result = results[0];
            let rsltAdrComponent = result.address_components;
            let resultLength = rsltAdrComponent.length;
         if (result != null) {
      console.log(rsltAdrComponent[resultLength - 8].short_name)
      // this.address = rsltAdrComponent[resultLength - 8].short_name;
    } else {
      console.log('No address available!');
    }
   }
  });
}
```